# How can I get poisson simulation of one car over the rest of cars in R?

Tags: r, simulation, poisson

I have the mtcars dataset
What I want is to make a simulation using a Poisson distribution
The basic idea is to simulate hp using `rpois()` and compare it to the rest of the cars to see how many times one car has a lower hp than the other. That way I can have the probability that a car has a lower hp than the rest of the cars. I am using this example for simplicity in reality I am using golf players and base on their average score I want to know what is the probability to win the tournament

I can test the probability of one car has less hp than another by using their score

```
n1 = 93
n2 = 100
sum(rpois(1000, n1) < rpois(1000, n2))/1000
```

In this case, I am testing Mazda RX4 and Datsun 710
I would like a way to find this probability but using the whole sample, in other words, how many times
Mazda RX4 has less hp from the Poisson simulation than the rest of the cars in the sample

Comment: it doesn't seem like the poisson distribution is appropriate for this case.  This answer suggest you should look into bayesian inference/networks which makes more sense: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769518/algorithm-to-calculate-the-odds-of-a-team-winning-a-sports-match-given-full-hist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of comparing all cars with all cars using `outer` and a vectorized comparison function, `g`.

```
f <- function(n1, n2){
  mean(rpois(1000, n1) < rpois(1000, n2))
}
g <- Vectorize(f, c("n1", "n2"))
res <- outer(mtcars$hp, mtcars$hp, g)
dimnames(res) <- list(row.names(mtcars), row.names(mtcars))
```

Comment: The third column (datsun710) with the first row (Mazda Rx4) gives me the probability of Datsun has lower hp than Mazda rx4?

Comment: @PastorSoto Yes, that's it.

Comment: I was checking and it seems that is the other way around. The probability that one car has a lower mpg is in the rows compared to the columns. In the example, I think it should be the probability that Mazda RX4 has lower hp than Datsun 710. It is possible for you to check and let me know. Also, Using this code can I find the probability that one car has the lowest hp than the rest of the cars?